# Personal Finance Management Tool

Tags: c++, beginner

I'm looking for feedback on this Personal Finance tool. I want to know what I've done well and what I haven't done so well. Please don't criticise the fact I've used Hungarian notation, it's required in my university assignment and I know I probably should be using classes but at the moment I'm just sticking to the procedural approach.

> ### Scenario
>
> A reputable bank has asked you to create a personal finance management
> program. The program will need to be able to take the user's monthly
> wage, their monthly bills, and any weekly bills that they may occur.
> This will then be broken down to find out how much of their wages they
> will then have left to save.
>
> The user should be able to enter any amount of monthly bills and
> weekly bills. The user should also have the option to add other users
> from their household to be handled within the calculations.
>
> Once all of the relevant information has been included, an overview of
> the bills against a weekly, monthly and yearly cost should be output.
>
> ### Inputs
>
> - User's Name (Must be more than 1)
> - Monthly Wage (Must be more than 1)
> - The different bills the user has to pay (Per Person)
>
> ### Outputs
>
> - User's Name
> - Weekly, Monthly, Yearly Wage Total
> - Weekly, Monthly, Yearly Bills Total
> - Total Spent on Bills
> - Total left to Save
> - 10% over and under the total that can be saved
> - How much can be saved per month
> - 10% over and under the total that can be saved per month

---

## The code

#### `Personal Finance Management.cpp`

This file contains the `main` function. Program execution begins and ends there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void Addusers(vector<string>&sUserName)
{
    string sUserNameInput = "";
    cout << "\nEnter the name of household member: ";
    cin >> sUserNameInput;
    sUserName.push_back(sUserNameInput);
}
void AddMonthlyWage(vector<string>&sUserName,vector<double> &dMonthlyWage)
{
    double dInputMonthlyWage = 0;
    cout << "\n" << *sUserName.rbegin() << "'s monthly income: ";
    cin >> dInputMonthlyWage;
    dMonthlyWage.push_back(dInputMonthlyWage);
}

void YearlyAmount(vector<double>&dYearlySalary,vector<double>&dMonthlyWage, vector<string>&sUserName)
{
    double dYearlySalaryProcess = 0;
    dYearlySalaryProcess = *dMonthlyWage.rbegin() * 12;
    dYearlySalary.push_back(dYearlySalaryProcess);
}

void WeeklyAmount(vector<double>&dYearlySalary, vector<double>&dWeeklySalary, vector<string>&sUserName)
{
    double dWeeklySalaryProcess = 0;
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount != sUserName.size(); iCount++)
    {
    dWeeklySalaryProcess = (*dYearlySalary.rbegin() / 12) / 4;
    dWeeklySalary.push_back(dWeeklySalaryProcess);
    }
}

double dCalculateBillAmounts(double dYearlySalary,const double dIncomeTax, double dWaterBill, double dElectricityBill)
{
    double dTotalBillProcess = 0;
    dTotalBillProcess = (dYearlySalary * dIncomeTax) + dWaterBill + dElectricityBill;
    return dTotalBillProcess;
}

void BillAmounts(vector<double> &dYearlySalary, vector<string>&sUserName, vector<double>&dTotalBill)
{
    const double dIncomeTax = 0.1;
    vector<double> dWaterBill;
    vector<double> dElectricityBill;
    double dTotalBillProcess = 0;
    double dInputBill = 0;
    
    cout << "\nPlease enter " << *sUserName.rbegin() << "'s water bill: ";
    cin >> dInputBill;
    dWaterBill.push_back(dInputBill);
        

    cout << "\nPlease enter " << *sUserName.rbegin() << "'s electricity bill: ";
    cin >> dInputBill;
    dElectricityBill.push_back(dInputBill);
    
    dTotalBillProcess = dCalculateBillAmounts(*dYearlySalary.rbegin(), dIncomeTax, *dWaterBill.rbegin(), *dElectricityBill.rbegin());
    dTotalBill.push_back(dTotalBillProcess);

}
double CalculateMonthly(double dAmount)
{
    double dCalculateMonthlyProcess = dAmount / 12;
    return dCalculateMonthlyProcess;
}
double CalculateWeekly(double dAmount)
{
    double dCalculateWeeklyProcess = dAmount / 54;
    return dCalculateWeeklyProcess;
}
double TotalOver(double dAmount, double dPercentage)
{
    double dPercentageUnder = dAmount + (dAmount * dPercentage);
    return dPercentageUnder;
}
double TotalUnder(double dAmount, double dPercentage)
{
    double dPercentageOver = dAmount - (dAmount * dPercentage);
    return dPercentageOver;
}

void DisplayResults(vector<string> &sUserName, vector<double> &dMonthlyWage, vector<double> &dTotalBill, vector<double> &dYearlySalary,vector<double> &dWeeklySalary)
{
    vector<double> dTotalSavings;
    double dTotalSavingsProcess = 0;
    double dSavingsOverProcess = 0;
    double dSavingsUnderProcess = 0;
    vector<double> dSavingsOverPercentage;
    vector<double> dSavingsUnderPercentage;
    const double dPercentage = 0.1;
    
    vector<double> dBillsOverPercentage;
    vector<double> dBillsUnderPercentage;
    double dBillsOverProcess = 0;
    double dBillsUnderProcess = 0;
    
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount != sUserName.size(); iCount++)
    {
        cout << "\nResults for - " << sUserName.at(iCount) << ".";
        cout << "\n--Salary--";
        cout << "\nYearly salary is: £" << dYearlySalary.at(iCount) << ".";
        cout << "\nMonthly salary: £" << dMonthlyWage.at(iCount) << ".";
        cout << "\nWeekly salary is: £" << dWeeklySalary.at(iCount) << ".";
        cout << "\n--Bills--";
        cout << "\nTotal spent on bills: £" << dTotalBill.at(iCount) << ".";
        cout << "\nMonthly bill cost: £" << CalculateMonthly(dTotalBill.at(iCount)) << ".";
        cout << "\nWeekly bill cost: £" << CalculateWeekly(dTotalBill.at(iCount)) << ".";
        
        cout << "\n--Savings over and under 10%--";
        dTotalSavingsProcess = dYearlySalary.at(iCount) - dTotalBill.at(iCount);
        dTotalSavings.push_back(dTotalSavingsProcess);
        cout << "\nTotal savings: £" << dTotalSavings.at(iCount);
        
        dSavingsOverProcess = TotalOver(dTotalSavings.at(iCount), dPercentage);
        dSavingsOverPercentage.push_back(dSavingsOverProcess);
        cout << "\n" << dPercentage * 100 << "% over their total savings: £" << dSavingsOverPercentage.at(iCount);
        
        dSavingsUnderProcess = TotalUnder(dTotalSavings.at(iCount),dPercentage);
        dSavingsUnderPercentage.push_back(dSavingsUnderProcess);
        cout << "\n" << dPercentage * 100 << "% under their total savings: £" << dSavingsUnderPercentage.at(iCount);
        cout << "\n--Bills over and under 10%--";
        dBillsOverProcess = TotalOver(dTotalBill.at(iCount), dPercentage);
        dBillsOverPercentage.push_back(dBillsOverProcess);
        cout << "\n" << dPercentage * 100 << "% over their total bills: £" << dBillsOverPercentage.at(iCount);
        
        dBillsUnderProcess = TotalUnder(dTotalBill.at(iCount),dPercentage);
        dBillsUnderPercentage.push_back(dBillsUnderProcess);
        cout << "\n" << dPercentage * 100 << "% under their total bills: £" << dBillsUnderPercentage.at(iCount);
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void ContinueOptions(bool &bExit)
{
    char cSelection = 0;
    cout << "Do you wish to add another family member? (Y/N) ";
    cin >> cSelection;
    cSelection = toupper(cSelection);
    if(cSelection == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\nAdd a new family member";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nGoodbye!";
        bExit = true;
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<string>sUserName;
    vector<double>dMonthlyWage;
    vector<double>dYearlySalary;
    vector<double>dWeeklySalary;
    vector<double>dTotalBills;
    bool bExit = false;
    do
    {
        //Procedure 1
        Addusers(sUserName);
        //Procedure 2
        AddMonthlyWage(sUserName,dMonthlyWage);
        //Procedure 3
        YearlyAmount(dYearlySalary,dMonthlyWage, sUserName);
        //Procedure 4
        WeeklyAmount(dYearlySalary,dWeeklySalary, sUserName);
        //Procedure 5
        BillAmounts(dYearlySalary,sUserName,dTotalBills);
        //Procedure 6
        DisplayResults(sUserName, dMonthlyWage,dTotalBills,dYearlySalary,dWeeklySalary);
        //Procedure 7
        ContinueOptions(bExit);
    }while(bExit == false);
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is it explicitly required to not to use classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Avoid `using namespace std`

That's not one of the namespaces designed for wholesale import into the global namespace.  Such a `using` directive denies you the advantages that namespaces bring.

## Always check your inputs

See the problem here?

> ```
> cin >> sUserNameInput;
> sUserName.push_back(sUserNameInput);
> ```

If the `>>` operator fails, `sUserNameInput` will still be empty.  But the requirement says it must be greater than 1 (presumably meaning the name length), so we fail.

Always check that `>>` was successful, either by testing the stream (it has a conversion to `bool`) or by setting it to throw exceptions (and then handle the exceptions appropriately).

## Use `const` on reference parameters that we're not changing.

For example, `YearlyAmount()` only needs to read `dMonthlyWage`, not modify it, and doesn't use `sUserName` at all:

```
void YearlyAmount(std::vector<double>& dYearlySalary,
                  std::vector<double> const& dMonthlyWage,
                  std::vector<string>&)
```

We should probably just remove the unused paramater.

## Accessing last element

`std::vector()` provides `back()` as a more convenient way to write `*v.rbegin()`.

## Lines end in `\n`

We need to print `\n` at the *end* of each line, not at its beginning.

## `std::toupper()` takes an `int` value

Arguments to character conversion functions take the *unsigned* value of a character, represented as `int`.  We need to cast to `unsigned char` before the promotion to `int` happens, to avoid passing negative values.

## Prefer returning a value than writing to a reference.

`ContinueOptions` has a single return value, so return it.  Look how much clearer that is:

> ```
> bool bExit = false;
> do
> {
>     ...
>     ContinueOptions(bExit);
> }while(bExit == false);
> ```

That becomes:

```
do
{
    ...
} while(ContinueOptions());
```

That's with a function like this:

```
bool ContinueOptions()
{
    std::cout << "Do you wish to add another family member? (y/N) ";
    char cSelection;
    std::cin >> cSelection;
    if (!std::cin) {
        // input failed - assume "no"
        return false;
    }
    bool go_again = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(cSelection)) == 'Y';
    std::cout << (go_again ? "Add a new family member\n" : "Goodbye!\n");
    return go_again;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for reviewing my program. You’ve mentioned a lot of interesting points which I have taken on board. I’m a little lost on your second point about inputs. I can’t see anything wrong? I’d appreciate if you elaborate on that. I’m very glad you told me about the last point because I was thinking to myself there must be a better way. Thanks for that!

Comment: Input can go wrong for all sorts of reasons - end of file (or broken connection), input that fails to convert (e.g. entering letters when a number was required), etc.  If we always assume input is successful, and never check for errors, we'll get strange results.  Look at my version of `ContinueOptions` for a very simple error check - `if (!std::cin)`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! Thanks very much! I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

### Complexity

The code does a pretty good job of following the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

The exception to this is the function `DisplayResults()` which is too complex (does too much in one function). Based on the name of the function it should do exactly one thing, which is display the results.

The `Addusers()` function function should be responsible for calling all the functions to add user information, there should be a new function call `AddUserName()`.

Many of the functions would require less parameters if user was a class and that would greatly simplify the implementation.

In the `calculate` functions the code can simply return the calculation rather than assigning it to a variable and then returning the variable. It might be possible to write these functions as [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) rather than functions.

### Avoid `using namespace std`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

### Useless Comments

The comments in `main()` of the form `//Procedure N` really don't help explain anything. Comments should be used to explain why the code may be doing something that a programmer can't infer by reading self documenting code. Given the function and variable names in the program this code is self documenting code.

Comment: Thanks so much for reviewing my program. Can you elaborate about the return user function? I’d appreciate that greatly. I will definitely take on board about the display procedure I will fix that! Many thanks!

Comment: To return `user` there should be a `user` class or struct. What I was describing above is that all necessary vectors should be passed into the `AddUser` function (note, not plural) and that the `AddUser` function should call each of the functions that get input. I would put off all calculations until all user information has been added. While looking into an answer for your comment I noticed that the function `BillAmounts` has to vectors that aren't used as vectors, this looks like a bug waiting to happen.